# Artificial Claws, Good Question?:

Tags: discussion

I think this might be appropriate question for Main... but I think it belongs more on History.SE or something... Am I wrong?

**Have artificial claws, as in those that appear in video games and the like, been used in any martial art?**

- ***It seems the answer's "Yes", but the info on Bujinkan, which uses Shuko, a.k.a Hand-claws, makes it out to seem... flaky...***

Hmm... [Multiple bladed retractable claw weapon](http://www.google.com/patents/US4096629)

Those links at the very bottom have got more combat-glove type stuff...

Or [Hand covering claw](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/recettear/images/e/ed/09griff_00.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100924041202)

Those are different... and would be used differently...

Well, they existed historically, look at the pics linked from here:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WolverineClaws

***Someone else can adopt this question if they want...***

Answer (score 3):

This would appear to be about both equipment and the historical aspects of the martial arts, so would be on topic. It could be quite an interesting question if asked well.

Comment: So... should I also ask: "If not, why?" 'Cause right now, it's just a Yes/No Question...

Comment: Ah, well... posting it anyways...